# Why is this code vulnerable to buffer overflow?

Tags: security, stack, buffer-overflow

```
void cpy(char* b) {
    char values[1024];
    strcpy(b, values);
    fprint(values);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc == 1 || strlen(argv[1]) > 1024) {
        fprint("Nope!\n");
        return 1;
}
    cpy(argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is this code vulnerable to buffer overflow? I think it has something to do with the "strcpy" part but I'm not sure...

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure it's the best idea to post your homework problems on this site.  If you don't understand the material in the least but mysteriously get an "A" on your homework, how will you explain your eventual "F" on the final exam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short story: The arguments on `strcpy` are switched.

Long story: `strcpy` copies *from the second to the first* argument.

Let us make a quick analysis. In `main`, the code checks that `argv[1]` is at most 1023+1 (NUL byte) characters long. `argv[1]` is then passed to `cpy` as first and only argument and is available there as `b`.

In `cpy`, there’s also an uninitialised array of char called `values`, which is allocated to be 1024 characters long.

Now, `strcpy` is instructed to copy from `values` into `b`. As we know, `b` is the pointer obtained from `argv[1]`, and thus has at most 1024 chars of space. `values` is reserved for 1024 characters, but uninitialised. Thus, it may or may not contain a NUL byte in those 1024 characters.

If it happens to contain a NUL byte before the bounds of `argv[1]` are reached, everything is fine. If it does not, two things can happen:

- if `argv[1]` is exactly 1023 characters long (+ terminating NUL byte), out of bounds reads (on `values`) and writes (on `argv[1]`) will happen.
- if `argv[1]` is less than 1023 characters long, out of bounds writes on `argv[1]` will happen, and by extension there may also happen out of bounds reads on `values`, if the program survives the out of bounds writes.

Depending on what fprint is (I don’t have a manpage for it on my system), there may be other issues in the code.

Comment: ohh I see. So the array "values" should be initialized always with one position more than "b"? Or is there a better option?

Comment: Entirely depends on what you want to achieve. The code as it stands does not make much sense either way. Maybe you could explain what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you use a array of char as there is no operator to mark the end of your array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fprint, it does not know when your string ends. It should end with a '\0'. So if you write something in your array with all the 1024 bytes set. The fprint command will read out of the memory to check if there is a '\0'... It will continue to read until it finds the end mark.